# How to distribute SQL database with application?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm developing a WPF desktop application, and the database currently resides in SQL Server Express 2012. The app is undergoing acceptance testing, and periodically I have to backup my database and restore it on the tester's PC. This is setting alarm bells ringing that distribution is going to be a pain when we come to start working with customers - I don't like the idea of them having to use SSMS.

I wondered if there was any way to distribute the mdf file and have my application connect to that "directly"? I've seen examples of connection strings that specify an MDF file/path, and wondered if it was really that simple or does it still need attaching in SSMS first? (I'm guessing so, otherwise how would you configure things like users and roles?).

Comment: If it's a local database, I prefer using some "file based" database (sqllite, sql compact, ...). Far more easier to deploy (a simple file copy), does not install a nuclear reactor on the client's computer (Sql Express run as a service, always consume memory and cpu, add a bunch of *what's that* entry in the start menu, etc.) and does not require a specific elevation of privilege in the setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most applications I've encountered run SQL CREATE scripts during the installation process. I'd prefer that way, because when you will have to change your schema some time in the future (and you will), you will have to do something similar, because you cannot exchange the old MDF (with your users' data) against an empty updated one.